# How do I batch convert WP51 files?

Tags: microsoft-word, rtf, wordperfect

How can I batch convert hundreds WordPerfect 5.1 files to simpler format such as RTF or TXT?

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility called "WPCONVERT" (or sometimes "Corel Convert") that is provided with most copies of WordPerfect.  It can also be downloaded from the Corel site:
ftp://ftp.corel.com/pub/WordPerfect/wpwin/70/wp_convert_utility.exe

There is some discussion of the utility at http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/wordtowpdos.html#corelconvert